# Zero Knowledge Proof for Correctness of the product of additive ElGamal Ciphers

Tags: elgamal-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

Suppose we use Additive ElGamal defined as follows:

> Let $(K,E,D)$ be a triple. The key-generator $K$ outputs the description of a
>   finite multiplicative group $G$ of prime order $q$, with three generators
>   $(g,h,f)$ which are set to be the public-key $p_k$ of the system; the
>   secret-key $s_k$ is set to the value $\log_g h$. For a public-key $(g,h,f)$
>   the encryption function $E(r,x)$ equals the tuple $(g^r, h^r, f^x)$. The
>   operations $+$ and $\oplus$ are defined as addition modulo $q$ and the
>   operation $\otimes$ is defined as point-wise multiplication over $G \times G$.  The
>   decryption function is denoted $D$. For a secret key $\log_g(h)$ given $(G,H)$ it returns
>   $H/G^{\log_g(h)}$ and then performs a brute-force search over all
>   possible values for $f^x$ to recover $x$.

So if I have two ElGamal encrypted cipher texts, $c_1= E(r_1,m_1)$ and $c_2 = E(r_2,m_2)$, I can do $c_1 \otimes c_2$ to get the same result as I would get if I did $E(r_1 \oplus r_2, m_1+m_2)$.

Can I somehow construct a zero knowledge proof, that, given a cipertext $c_1$, proves I only added one of $x$ possible ciphers?

Background would be an application for e-voting. Given a set of candidates, I want to prove that I just added one of the valid candidates (predetermined numbers) to the cipher. I already found a ZKP that shows that the Cipher I want to add is well-formed.

Comment: I encourage you to put in a bit more effort on formatting the question to be easily readable.  Did you know you can use Latex (Mathjax) on this site?  See the help center for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Gamal can be made additively homomorphic with the techniques shown here: [Can Elgamal be made additively homomorphic and how could it be used for E-voting?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3626/351) or [additive ElGamal encryption algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9000/351) (see also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13240/351).

If you use the additively homomorphic variant of El Gamal, you don't need any zero knowledge proof.  Anyone can verify that the addition was done correctly.  See [Proof of correctness of a homomorphic ElGamal sum](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10048/351), which shows exactly how.